# Android Studio - Naming Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Dear StackOverflow community,

I am having issues with my newest application. I am trying to make a Magic The Gathering Life Counter. I don't know how to change textViews, so I am simply using separate buttons for each player. When the player presses these buttons, a toast pops up with their life total. At least, that is what I have in mind. I have not written any code yet and I am working on the layout currently. In addition to the toast buttons, the player can add or subtract to their life total by pressing one of the buttons above their player button. These two buttons add one or subtract one to their life total. This is not the issue.

I thought it would be a good idea to be organized and rename all of the buttons to what they do. I was hoping to associate the OnClick functions with these button names. I tried to test the program out by loading it to my phone, but I forgot that I couldn't use + or - in the button name. The  software popped up with an error. I realized what I had missed.

Here's the really weird part. I went over to the attributes for one of the buttons and typed in a new name. When I pressed enter, the name just went back to its old, error-causing name.

I don't want to delete all of the buttons all over again, because it took me quite a while to get the layout working. Am I doing something wrong? If any of you need more information, please ask.

Thank you.

P.S.: Here is the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="Player 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p1minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="Player 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p2minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="Player 3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p3minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="Player 4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p4minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Player 5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p5minus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Player 6"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p6minus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Player 7"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p7minus" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:text="Player 8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p8minus" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p1plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p1minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p5plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p5plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p5minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p1plus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p6plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p6minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p2plus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p2plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p2minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p6plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p3plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p3minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p7plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p7plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p7minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p3plus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p4plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="122dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p4minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p8plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p8plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p8minus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p4plus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p3-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p4plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p7minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p7-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p8plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p3minus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p4-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p8minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p8-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p4minus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p2-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p3plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p6minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p6-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p7plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p2minus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p1-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p2plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/p5minus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/p1plus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/p5-"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p6plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/p1minus"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/p5plus"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_busy" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/10button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:text="10"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/20button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/20button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
        android:text="20"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/p1plus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/10button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/40button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:text="40"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/20button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the codes here?

Comment: It's not a problem with the code. I haven't done anything to the code. All I have messed with is the layout. When I try to switch the id name of a button, I press enter, and it goes back to its original name. It's so weird.

Comment: What I mean is the xml

Comment: Okay, it's a lot.

Comment: I can see your ids `android:id="@+id/p5+"` , maybe you can rename it to `p5_add` ?

Comment: Do you want me to do that in the XML or the activity layout page?

Comment: Both, XML and Java part.

Comment: It still comes up with this:

Comment: AAPT: error: id 'id/20button' has an invalid entry name.

Comment: Updated the XML.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I think I'm just going to start over, because I have to mess with the margins. XD

Comment: But how it can mess with the design? You just renamed the id only

Comment: It's being weird. I think it's just got to do with the sequence that I renamed them. For example, I told the code to attach to an object that wasn't there, and it just removed the margin. It shot to the top of the screen. Basically, all of the buttons are on the edges of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When renaming right click and go under "refactor" and hit "rename", also use characters a-z, A-Z, _, -, and 0-9 for variables. Do not use +.

Comment: Please be a little more specific. Where do I right click, and where is refractor?

Answer (score 1):

there are still + and - signs in your button Ids. Please remove that. If Android Studio is not allowing you to rename please try:

1. losing Project and Open again (File > Close Project)
2. rebuilding project (Build>Rebuild)
3. be sure to rename the buttons on every place you have used them like defining constraints.
   Hope that works.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I think I'm just going to start over, because the buttons are going all over the place when I rename them.

Comment: @Margorp13 That's great then. Go ahead.